# moment js diff function is failing in firefox and safari, but works fine in chrome

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using moment.js diff function to calculate difference of days between two dates. It works fine in chrome, but in firefox and safari returning NaN.

```
const month = 05;
const day = 05;
const year = 1987;
const date = new Date(year, month, day);
const dob = moment(date).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
const diff = moment().diff(dob, 'days', true);
```

the value of diff is correct in chrome, but returning NaN in firefox and safari.

Any help please?

Comment: You may be using an invalid date like `2007-02-30`. This happened to me.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome is more permissive with delimiters when it comes to dates, thus formatting the date with dashes works with Chrome but not with Firefox.

Try using the following :

```
const dob = moment(date).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Running your code in Firefox, you should get a warning saying that the date format you are using is not a RFC2822 or ISO format and momentjs fallbacks to using the vanilla [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) function, which gives different results across browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with formatting. The below fix worked for me.

**`const dob = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');`**

(or)

You can pass an array to diff function as below

**`moment().diff(moment([year, month, day]), 'days', true);`**

the diff function expects in the format of YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY/MM/DD.